# Airflow Error while setup and tear_down resources. object has no attribute 'as_teardown'

Tags: airflow

I'm going through the documentation to make sure in case of failure, teardown any resources that have been created.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/setup-and-teardown.html

https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-setup-teardown?tab=taskflow#as_setup-and-as_teardown-methods

to have setup and tear_down while creating/deleting cluster but it didnt worked. I tried with python operator as well but no luck.

```
setup_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="setup_task",
        python_callable=lambda: sleep_and_log("setup_task"),
    ).as_setup()
    
teardown_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="teardown_task",
    python_callable=lambda: sleep_and_log("teardown_task"),
).as_teardown(setups=[setup_task])
```

also via @task decorator -

```
@task
def my_setup_task():
    return "Setting up resources!"

@task
def my_teardown_task():
    return "Tearing down resources!"

my_setup_task_obj1 = my_setup_task()
my_tear_down_task_obj1 = my_setup_task()

my_setup_task_obj1.as_setup >> my_tear_down_task_obj1.as_tear_down
```

but no luck. getting error -

```
AttributeError: 'PlainXComArg' object has no attribute 'as_teardown'
```

Note : We don't want our DAG downstream task to get skipped. After tear_down step we still want our DAG to be in failed step for monitoring purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With classical operators

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator


with DAG("simple_setup_teardown", start_date=datetime(2024, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc), schedule=None):
    setup_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="setup_task",
        python_callable=lambda: print("setup_task"),
    )

    foo_bar = EmptyOperator(task_id="foo_bar")

    teardown_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="teardown_task",
        python_callable=lambda: print("teardown_task"),
    )

    setup_task.as_setup() >> foo_bar >> teardown_task.as_teardown(setups=setup_task)
```

With task flow operators

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

from airflow.decorators import task, dag

@dag(start_date=datetime(2024, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc), schedule=None)
def simple_setup_teardown():
    @task
    def setup_task():
        print("setup_task")

    @task
    def foo_bar():
        return 1 / 0

    @task
    def teardown_task():
        print("teardown_task")


    task_1 = setup_task()
    task_2 = foo_bar()
    task_3 = teardown_task()
    task_1 >> task_2 >> task_3.as_teardown(setups=task_1)

simple_setup_teardown()
```